# How to trigger a powershell script if some new items added in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, build-automation, powershell-2.0

We are having Sharepoint lists where users would update their required services.

Based on the service type we will take action.

For ex: Our Sharepoint site will have actions like "build" "Copy" "Sync in Appstore".

For each action there is a powershell script written.

If a request is raised for build, powershell script should be triggered.

How to achieve it using powershell?

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried.  For instance my first try would be to spawn a new process that runs the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at SharePoint [event receivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163318.aspx). Here's some example code written in PowerShell:

23JUN22 update - web archive with example code: https://web.archive.org/web/20141113023454/http://sharepintblog.com/2011/06/04/adding-event-receivers-with-powershell/ replacement for original link http://sharepintblog.com/2011/06/04/adding-event-receivers-with-powershell/

Comment: Why don't we name you as powershell encyclopedia buddy? :-) You are always giving the next step that i should go. thanks buddy

Comment: The URL has gone bad...

Answer (score 0):

Basically how you would in any other framework, i think you can give it a file path as a command line to run the script of the given location.